# dynamic loading class error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I'm writing program witch loads .class files in run time and calls main method. Code below.

```
File classDir = new File(pathToClass);
URL pathTo = classDir.toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{pathTo};
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
_class = cl.loadClass(className);
Method m = _class.getMethod("main", String[].class);
```

It builds and in execution I get this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LComplex;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
```

What I'm doing wrong

Files are placed in this pattern:

```
C:/dir/a/ccc.class
C:/dir/a/ccc.java
C:/dir/b/ccc.class
C:/dir/b/ccc.java
```

Comment: You can't have a java class named "class"!

Comment: It is named different. Just for concept I wrote class.class :)

Comment: OK ;) Nevertheless, you should give us more information. It seems, the class you've loaded references a class `Complex` that is not on the class path.

Comment: Thank you for observation. I will try to fix Complex problem and then give you feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Like isnot2bad told, Complex class was missing. After loading it error vanished